# Why does this very basic sails socket not work?

Tags: javascript, sockets, sails.js

just wondering why the following basic web socket is not working?

```
io.socket.on('user', function(event){
    console.log("RECIEVED EVENT:",event);
})
```

sails.io.js is included in my index and that code from above is located in an test.js file that lives under assets/js. I would expect that each time I make any request to the user api I would see a log. Oh and yes the user api does exist. I read the documentation and don't see where i am going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to register for events via the io.socket.get

```
// The automatically-created socket is exposed as io.socket.
// Use .on() to subscribe to the 'user' event on the client.
// This event is sent by the Sails "create", "update",
// "delete", "add" and "remove" blueprints to any socket that
// is subscribed to one or more User model instances.
io.socket.on('user', function gotHelloMessage (data) {
  console.log('User alert!', data);
});
// Using .get('/user') will retrieve a list of current User models,
// subscribe this socket to those models, AND subscribe this socket
// to notifications about new User models when they are created.
io.socket.get('/user', function gotResponse(body, response) {
  console.log('Current users: ', body);
})
```